# Maven failsafe plugin not using it.test property?

Tags: maven-failsafe-plugin

I have the following configuration for the maven failsafe plugin to run my integration tests (based on the documentation at [Failsafe Usage Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html#Using_jetty_and_maven-failsafe-plugin):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I try to run an individual test using:

```
mvn -Dit.test=MyLovelyTest failsafe:integration-test
```

It does not run my test.  It dies with the message: `No tests were executed`

If I remove the `execution` definition for `verify`, then it executes the test as expected.  Since I copied the plugin def from the official usage documentation, I'm wondering if there's a bug in the plugin, or is it something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your full pom file? Apart from that why didn't you name your integration test following the naming convention of maven-failsafe-plugin ?

Comment: I have the same problem currently. Specifying `it.test=FooIT` on the command line causes no tests to be executed and the build to fail. I also have a single execution with the `integration-test` and `verify` goals bound to their default phases.